# Where does this $1/2$ come from in this telescoping sum?

Tags: sequences-and-series

[image]

I'm going through the solution to this problem and I'm fine withe everything up until the line where $\frac 12$ is factored out; I'm not sure where it comes from.

What intermediate step am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\frac1{a(a+2)}=\frac12\left(\frac 1a-\frac1{a+2}\right)$$

Comment: Is this a standard formula that everyone should know? And does this formula apply more generally to $\frac{1}{a(a+k)}$?

Comment: It's something called a partial fractions decomposition. It's typically shown in calculus II courses, sometimes college algebra and precalculus.

Comment: @SeanRoberson Ok. Thank you. Is it assumed that I would instantly recognise that?

Comment: @SteveSmith Try adding/subtracting the fractions together like you would with $\frac12-\frac13$.  Then do that process backwards basically.  You recognize such things by practice, since it generally makes problems much easier.

Comment: @SimpleArt Could I do the same thing, then, with $$\frac{1}{5 \times 12}+\frac{1}{12 \times 19}+...+\frac{1}{1000 \times 1007} ?$$

Would I just write it as 1/7(1/5-1/12+1/12-1/19+...-1/1007)?

Comment: @SteveSmith Sure: $$\frac1{a(a+k)}=\frac1k\left(\frac1a-\frac1{a+k}\right)$$

Comment: @SteveSmith Just evalute it like $\frac{1}{ab}=\frac{A}{a}+\frac{B}{b}$

Comment: Awesome. Thanks!