# How can you prove that $\sum_{k=2}^n \frac{1}{k^2-1}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{3}{2}-\frac{2n+1}{n(n+1)}\right)$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, number-theory, real-numbers

Working through 1001  classical problems in number theory by De Koninck and Mericer it asks you find what the above series sums to. Completely failing in that (I have no intuition for inverses, and sums can often be difficult too; if anybody has comments on intuition for these that would be greatly appreciated too) I checked the solutions. But of course the solution is the equality, not the proof or intuition of it.

Does anybody know a proof, or would you be able to provide any intuition for understanding the relation?

$$\sum_{k=2}^n \frac{1}{k^2-1}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{3}{2}-\frac{2n+1}{n(n+1)}\right)$$

Comment: Hint: Do you have a telescope? Do you know the $a^2-b^2$ formula? If you still don’t get it, tag me and reply.

Comment: If you can't spot a telescope, use induction instead.

Comment: Use partial fraction decomposition to see the obvious telescoping

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where does this $1/2$ come from in this telescoping sum?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1956899/where-does-this-1-2-come-from-in-this-telescoping-sum)

Comment: Thank you for the comments, I don't know why I couldn't see the telescope. And thanks for the link to the other question, I couldn't find my sum when I searched before